# Using @Query with an index lookup in START

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a Spring Data Neo4j project (version 2.3.2.RELEASE) in which I have a tree of `BesoinNode` entities. The `BesoinNode` contains a "name" field and a Set of children :

```java
@NodeEntity
public class BesoinNode implements Besoin {

    @GraphId private Long id;

    //@Indexed(indexName = "indexBesoin", indexType = FULLTEXT) private String name;
    @Indexed(indexName = "indexBesoin") private String name;

    @RelatedTo(elementClass = BesoinNode.class, type = "hasChild", direction = OUTGOING)
    private Set<Besoin> besoins = new HashSet<Besoin>();

    // etc.
}
```

The associated repository is :

```java
public interface BesoinRepository extends GraphRepository<BesoinNode>, RelationshipOperationsRepository<BesoinNode>, NamedIndexRepository<BesoinNode> {

    // This query works
    @Query(value = "start parent=node({0}) match (parent)-[:hasChild]->(child) return child")
    Set<BesoinNode> findChildrenOf(Long id);

    // This query doesn't work
    @Query(value = "start parent=node:indexBesoin({name}) match (parent)-[:hasChild]->(child) return child")
    Set<BesoinNode> findChildrenOf(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

The first query works, but to call it, I first need to retrieve the id of the node, something which is not necessary and that I would like to avoid. That's what the second query is supposed to do but I cannot make it to work. What can possibly be wrong?

If I call `findChildrenOf("What a great name for a BesoinNode")` method I get a null pointer exception. The stacktrace is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.lucene.util.SimpleStringInterner.intern(SimpleStringInterner.java:54)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.StringHelper.intern(StringHelper.java:39)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.Term.<init>(Term.java:38)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:643)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1436)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1319)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1245)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.IndexType.query(IndexType.java:300)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:227)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:238)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.indexQuery(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:87)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$2.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:83)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$2.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:81)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.MonoDirectionalTraversalMatcher.findMatchingPaths(MonodirectionalTraversalMatcher.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.TraversalMatchPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(TraversalMatchPipe.scala:38)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.TraversalMatchPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(TraversalMatchPipe.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ClosingIterator.scala:36)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:86)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.hasNext(ClosingIterator.scala:35)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:29)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult$$anon$1.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:73)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:351)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:370)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.dispatchQuery(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.findChildrenOf(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am fighting with this problem since two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it suddenly works and the problem was that I mixed two styles of index lookups.

I needed to specify "name" for Lucene. So, instead of :

```
// This query doesn't work
@Query(value = "start parent=node:indexBesoin({name}) match (parent)-[:hasChild]->(child) return child")
Set<BesoinNode> findChildrenOf(@Param("name") String name);
```

I needed :

```
// This query works
@Query(value = "start parent=node:indexBesoin(name={name}) match (parent)-[:hasChild]->(child) return child")
Set<BesoinNode> findChildrenOf(@Param("name") String name);
```

The difference is the "indexBesoin(name={name})" instead of just "indexBesoin({name})".

It seems that there are different ways to use the index in Spring Data Neo4j and it's quite confusing.

Comment: It is not an issue of Spring data neo4j, it is an issue of how Neo4j / Cypher expose indices, you can do: `start n=node:index("key:value")` which is an index-query and sent down to the index, or `start n=node:index(key={value})` for exact lookups

Comment: @MichaelHunger Humm, in the first syntax ("key:value"), is it possible to substitute `value` with a parameter (e.g. `{name}`)? In my example, how can I use `index("name:name")` without having a problem with the double quotes?